# JSON response showing nil in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsjsonserialization

I am getting a response from a webservice. Yesterday I started getting nil JSON, but from response I am have proper byte data.

Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:byteData options:   NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"jsonDict %@",jsonDict);
```

byteData is not nil, but jsonDict is nil. 
My code is not working suddenly. 
Here the response that I am getting from the service :

```
{"DecryptDocAndCreatePDFResult":"abcdhdsgs"}
```

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Log `error`. What does it say?

Comment: this coding is fine, show ur NSLog(@"jsonDict %@",jsonDict);

Comment: Log error is - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7872cf50 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check that your `JSON` is comes or not

```
NSString *tmp=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:byteData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"before %@", tmp);


after that start your 

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:byteData options:   NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];    //  try this NSJSONReadingMutableContainers into NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
NSLog(@"jsonDict %@",jsonDict);
```

the some type of  `NSJSONReadingOptions` is

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSJSONReadingOptions) {
NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves = (1UL << 1),
NSJSONReadingAllowFragments = (1UL << 2)
KNilOptions //  I added here 
};
```

Comment: first check that here o/p is comes or not NSLog(@"before %@", tmp);

Comment: have a nice day my friend

Answer (score 0):

First off all before convert to the json. check the NSString O/p

```
 NSString *strResponce=[[NSString alloc]initWithData: byteData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",strResponce);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.